# Spring MVC Annotations Date Range Validation

Tags: spring, validation, annotations, bean-validation

What is the better way to to implement date range validation for the following use case:

1. Date should be before or after specified date;
2. The Time difference in comparison with current time (now) is greater/less then some period of time. (As example check whether User is more than 21 years old).

The one way to implement this is to put this functionality inside validators. And in every controller write this logic for myself.

In order to have better re-use it's possible to create [custom annotation](http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-using-annotation-and-custom-validator-implementation).
Looking into Existing annotations especially:

1. [@Past](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Past.html)
2. [@Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Future.html)

These annotations are not reusable at all. They've designed for single condition and for me it's a question why it's designed in  such way.

I tend to implement these use cases with creation of new custom annotation. Can anybody suggest better approach or provide some argument against Spring custom annotations?